# How to define Environments and Constants in LinqPad6?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, linqpad, linqpad6

I use LinqPad to query data from microservices. My problem is that i've got 3 environments (test, integration, production).
Every environment has it's own configuration (URLs, Users etc.).

Is it possible to create some kind of environment-constants for my LinqPad-Scripts?

My config could look like this:

**Test:**

```json
{
    "productServiceUrl"="myDevServer.com/product.service",
    "User"="DevUser",
    "Password"="TopSecret"
}
```

**Int:**

```json
{
    "productServiceUrl"="myIntServer.com/product.service",
    "User"="IntUser",
    "Password"="TopSecret2"
}
```

**Prod:**

```json
{
    "productServiceUrl"="myProdServer.com/product.service",
    "User"="ProdUser",
    "Password"="TopSecret3"
}
```

And in myscript is want to user something like this:

```cs
var myProductService = new MyProductClient(CurrentEnvironmentConfig.ProductServiceUrl);
```

Comment: You can use the `#load`directive to merge another query in that defines a `Config` class and merge a second query that defines the `CurrentEnvironmentConfig`? How would you expect to set the current environment?

Comment: You can also write code in "My Extensions" (Shift+Ctrl+Y) which is visible to all queries. You could define your CurrentEnvironmentConfig class there.

Comment: LINQPad can also be run in a portable mode which allows you to set different configs, queries, and My Extensions. We use it to clone a Git repo and run separate queries to allow working on different code branches.